# Nodejs debug npm module doesnt print out debug statements

Tags: node.js, debugging

I start my nodejs application with the node debug npm module: 
"DEBUG=* & node bin/app.js" .

However the console output does not show the debugging statement, but with [1] and the PID of the node process. e.g

user@machine:/c/Users/user/Documents/appfolder$ DEBUG=* & node bin/app.js

[1] 290

Obvious the node application is running as a background process.
How do I get the decorated output statements like in the description of the debug npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

console.log() statement are printed in the console. But not the debug() statements.

Comment: Re-read the examples you linked to; if you're using Windows cmd you need `set`. If you're using e.g. git bash remove the `&`

Comment: I forget to say that I am using WSL on a windows machine. The command is used correctly and the node application is started,but the debug() statements are not printed to console.

Comment: WSL you can just use the Linux version, remove the `&`.

Comment: Thanks **DEBUG=* node bin/app.js** is working